# How can i append a view to existing html markup using backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

Can anybody give a small example about how to load a new div container based on a mouse click, using Backbone.js? I would like to add a new div container to my already existing html contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a view class:

```
events: { "click #myButton": "insertDiv" }

insertDiv: function(event) {
    this.$el.append("<div>...</div>");
}
```

Comment: How to append a div with a particulr id, say; div_id, which is already defined in an html file?

Comment: Try `this.$el.append( $("#div_id").html() )`